# Clarification on Java robot commands

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am automating file upload in Selenium using Java Robot. Below is my code.

```
StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(imageFileName);
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(stringSelection, null);
Robot robot;
try {
    robot = new Robot();
    //imitate mouse events like ENTER, CTRL+C, CTRL+V
    robot.delay(250);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
} catch (AWTException e) {
    logger.debug(e);
    logger.debug("Error while dealing with non-browser window");
}
```

The problem occurs if in the window "Recent" option is selected.

[image]

If in the window it points to "Computer" then I get the location search bar where I can paste the file path and click on open.

[image]

Please let me know how to handle if in the window it is pointing to anything other than "Computer". If it is pointing to something else I want to click on Computer and execute.

Comment: Believe Ctrl+Alt+L or Ctrl+L can be used to directly highlight the location bar

Comment: Thank you. I will try this.